# take a char and print out from char to 'a' and reverse it should be recursive

Tags: python, recursion, char

this code should take a char as an argument and print out that char in alphabetically order to 'a' and reverse to char.

```
>>> characters('d')
d c b a b c d
```

this is what Ii wrote so far but it is not the correct output

```
def characters(char):
    numb=ord(char)
    while numb>ord('a'):
>>      print chr(numb),
        numb=numb-1

    return


>>> characters('h')
g f e d c b a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def characters(c):
  print ' '.join(map(chr, range(ord(c), ord('a'), -1) + range(ord('a'), ord(c)+1)))

>>> characters('d')
d c b a b c d
```

or

```
def characters(c):
  for n in xrange(ord(c), ord('a'), -1):
    print chr(n),
  for n in xrange(ord('a'), ord(c)+1):
   print chr(n),
  print
```

Comment: Your output differs from the OP's.

Comment: I can't use a built-in function like .join

Comment: @user531225: Why can't you use a builtin function like join?

Comment: @user531225 ord and chr are also builtins. If you can't use builtins, then why did you use them in your question?

Comment: cause they were the only ones which was allowed

Comment: no it ain't ... i'm studying for an exam .. and  try to solve some old exam questions

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're halfway there as it stands. Now you just have to figure out how to take numb back to your letter.

In order to make it go backwards in the alphabet, you're using `numb=numb-1`. So in order to make it go forward in the alphabet, what would be the opposite of that? Then you could put that in another loop afterwards.